# Do smart pointers break the principle of minimizing #includes in header files?

Tags: c++

I prefer to minimize the use of `#include` in my header files, using forward declarations wherever possible, and I believe this is considered good practice.

It works great if I have a method declaration like:

```
bool IsFlagSet(MyObject *pObj);
```

However if I have `typedef Ptr<MyObject> MyObjectPtr` in `MyObject.h` and the API changes to:

```
bool IsFlagSet(MyObjectPtr pObj);
```

Do I not now *have* to `#include "MyObject.h"`? Is there any way around this, or is it just the price one pays for using smart pointers?

Comment: Why not `bool IsFlagSet(Ptr<MyObject> pObj);`?

Comment: If you pass smart pointer by reference, won't it work as before?

Comment: P.S. Unless the function is changing ownership of the smart pointer, there's no need to use a smart pointer in the interface. Use a dumb one instead and use the smart pointer's `get` at the calling site.

Comment: Many 3rd-party libs pass pointer objects by value though, I am not asking how to change my code but how to work with other peoples'!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you do not have to. You can define a type alias for an incomplete class, and template arguments can be incomplete types (see Paragraph 14.3.1/2 of the C++11 Standard):

```
#include <memory>

struct C;

typedef std::shared_ptr<C> ptrC; // C is incomplete here

struct C { void foo() { } };

int main()
{
    ptrC p = std::make_shared<C>();
    p->foo();
}
```

As correctly mentioned by [Pubby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/964135/pubby) in the comments, function declarations do not require the types mentioned in their signature to be complete either:

```
struct C;

void foo(C); // C is incomplete here

struct C { };

#include <iostream>

void foo(C)
{
    std::cout << "foo(C)" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    C c;
    foo(c);
}
```

Comment: You might want to add that function declarations don't need complete types either.

Comment: @Pubby: Thank you, added that to the answer

Answer (score 3):

No, `std::shared_ptr<T>` is explicitly designed to work when `T` is only forward-declared. Of course, this does not work for all cases, but the principle is the same as for a plain pointer. If `T` is forward-declared, you can do anything with `std::shared_ptr<T>` that you could do with `T*`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use typedef with incomplete type.

But isn't it better to use full name of the smart pointer type?

`MyClassPtr` is of course much shorter, but `std::unique_ptr<MyClass>` actually tells us how to use this pointer. So for not very long names I suggest using full names of smart pointers.

Comment: Doesn't help if someone else already wrote the code. This pattern `typedef Ptr<Type> TypePtr` is one I see in several libraries both open-source and proprietary.